# invalid string: control character U+000A (LF) must be escaped to \u000A

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, unicode

I have developed a python code which saves the data in BigQuery. My BigQuery table contains a column "details" which is of JSON type. The code usually works fine but when it encounters data which contain LF unicode character, it gives error (when saving data into the "details" column) as below-

> 400 Invalid JSON literal: syntax error while parsing value - invalid string: control character U+000A (LF) must be escaped to \u000A or \n

I checked with other unicode characters, the issue comes only when encountering unicode characters similar to linebreaks, like \u000A, \u000B, \u000C etc.

I tried encoding the data to utf-8 format before saving in BigQuery, but that also gives error -

> TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

I know I can manually replace some of these characters by their specific counterparts like \n, \r, \f etc, but I am looking for a more robust way to do this. Another reason for not manually replacing is that the incoming data can contain any new unicode character. Is there any other way to process and save this kind of data?

**EDIT: Reproducible example**

```
some_text = chr(40960) + 'abcd' + chr(1972) + '\u000a' + u'aあä'
details = {'details_text': some_text}
details['other_key'] = 'other_val'
details = json.dumps(details)
```

Then I insert this data into BigQuery table

```
myquery = f"""INSERT INTO `database.mytable`
VALUES('value1', JSON '''{details}''', 'value2')"""
query_job = bq_client.query(myquery, location = location)
query_job.run()
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you convert (some of) the data to JSON, and save that in  BigQuery? If so, how are you doing the conversion to JSON?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @9769953 I have added in the example how I am doing the conversion.

Comment: @JosefZ I have added an example

Comment: Should there be a space between JSON and the string (`'''{details}'''`)? That's what [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#json_literals) suggests.

Comment: I ran your Python code, and the final JSON string looks fine; the `details_text` string looks like `"\\ua000abcd\\u07b4\\na\\u3042\\u00e4"`: all escaped backslashes, so escaped control codes.

Comment: @9769953 Yes there is a space. I forgot to add here while writing this question. And the string looks fine but have you tried to save in BigQuery? Running insert query is where it gives error.

Comment: The JSON is fine.  Try using a parameterized query instead of a format string.  It prevents SQL injection attacks and is best practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem is when there is a new line '\n', and to solve it you have to put '\\n'
Create the following code to take care of that character type and replace it

```
def translate_special_characters(text):
  return re.sub(r"(\"|\'|\n|\\n)", lambda m: {'"': r"\"", "'": r"\'", "\n": r"\\n", "\\n": r"\\n"}[m.group()], text)
```

You just have to replace the following part of your code:

```
details = translate_special_characters(json.dumps(details))
```

Comment: Yes, already tried it. My point is rather than explicitly replacing each character, is there any other way to achieve the same result?